# How can I get Wi-Fi protocol version (802.11 a/b/g/n) in Android?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I cannot find out method to get Wi-Fi protocol version (I mean a/b/g/n) in Android API or Developer's guide. I also tried to get Wi-Fi info through

> `adb shell dumpsys wifi`

I see "key_mgmt" info for example "key_mgmt=WPA2/IEEE 802.1X/EAP". But the info does not indicate which version it is. Is there any calculation methods or adb tools can help me to get the protocol version(a/b/g/n)?

*(Update)*
Linux command `iwlist wlan0 scan` includes **Protocol** info which is exactly what I want (e.g. IEEE 802.11bg). But, `iwlist` is not a built-in function in Android. I want to get the info without root permission.

Comment: Is there any command in `adb shell` like **Windows**' `netsh` command? I found out the info **Radio type** indicating 802.11a/b/g/n with command `netsh wlan show all`.